# How to do request in ssr component Strapi + Next js App Router with GraphQL + Apollo

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, strapi

**I have set up a next js project with strapi and I am querying with GraphQL + Apollo, and now I want to query using Apollo in ssr component, I get this error** -

> Error: Attempted to call query() from the server but query is on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.

How to make a request to use Apollo in an SSR component without using **"@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr"** or maybe someone knows good alternatives to [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/)

My code

```
lib/client.tsx

"use client";

import { InMemoryCache, ApolloClient, ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

const STRAPI_URL = process.env.STRAPI_URL || "http://localhost:1337";

export function createApolloClient() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: `${STRAPI_URL}/graphql`,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });
  return client;
}
export const client = createApolloClient();

export function ApolloWrapper({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
}
```

```
app/page.tsx

import { RootFooter, RootMain } from "@/compoents/organisms";
import { GETQUERY } from "@/query/schema";

import { client } from "@/lib/client";

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await client.query({
    query: GETQUERY
  });
  console.log(data, "data");
  return (
    <>
      <RootMain>
        <h1 className="text-white">{}</h1>
      </RootMain>
      <RootFooter />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
query/schema.ts

import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GETQUERY = gql`
  {
    todos(sort: "id:desc") {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          todoText
          createdAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here doesn't come from the apollo library but the fact that you marked your `lib/client.tsx` file with the directive `"use client"`. (I assume it is necessary for the `ApolloWrapper` component, in this case, create a separate file just for it)

Remove that directive and it should work fine.